# Calculate the convolution of the product of two identical sine functions. (5.6-7)

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform, solution-verification, convolution

**Request**

I am very new to this so please bear with me. I cannot duplicate the answer in the book although I do get very close. This tells me that my method is correct but I am making another kind of error -- perhaps in my trigonometry or integral?

**Given**:

Find the convolution of $f(t)=sin(\omega t)$ and $g(t)=sin(\omega t)$.

$$h(t)=(f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$

**My Solution**:

$$h(t)=\sin(\omega t)*\sin(\omega t)=\int_0^t\sin(\omega \tau)\cdot \sin(\omega(t-\tau)d\tau$$

Apply the trigonometric product formula identity...

$$=-\int_0^t \sin(\omega \tau)\cdot \sin(\omega(\tau-t)d\tau=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t[\cos(\omega t)+\cos(2\omega\tau-\omega t)]d\tau$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\tau \cos(\omega t)-\frac{\sin(2\omega\tau-t\omega)}{2\omega}\right]_0^t$$

A bit messy just do a little house cleaning before applying bounds...

$$=\left[\frac{sin(2\omega\tau-t\omega)}{4\omega}-\frac{\tau cos(\omega t)}{2}-\right]_0^t=\frac{sin(\omega t)}{4\omega}-\frac{t cos(\omega t)}{2}-0+0$$

$$h(t)=\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{4\omega}-\frac{t \cos(\omega t)}{2}$$

**Answer in Text**:

$$h(t)=\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{2\omega}-\frac{t \cos(\omega t)}{2}$$

**Question**

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convolution Product $\sin t *\sin t$ by complex replacement.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156584/convolution-product-sin-t-sin-t-by-complex-replacement)

Comment: @dustin I really appreciate your help but this is not a duplicate of that other problem because of the following reasons:

(1.) Complex replacement is not an option in my text for this problem. (2.) My text suggests using a trigonometric product formula identity as does that other post but it goes no further. (3.) I followed the technique suggested in the book and cannot duplicate the same answer. (4.) The other post does not answer my question. Please unflag it as possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the evaluation of the term

$$\frac{\sin(2\omega\tau-\omega t)}{4\omega}{\Huge|}_0^t$$

Note that you get contributions for $\tau=t$ *and* for $\tau=0$:

$$\frac{\sin(2\omega\tau-\omega t)}{4\omega}{\Huge|}_0^t=\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{4\omega}-\frac{\sin(-\omega t)}{4\omega}=\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{2\omega}$$